# Batch resize images with different background colors

Tags: resize, batch-processing, photoshop

My goal is to batch resize images with different background colours.

I already used Photoshop to batch process and centre (horizontal and vertical align) 2000 different images into square 200x200 tiles on a white background (the images are different in size, background colour, and sometimes file-type).

I can process and batch resize the images and place them on a white 200x200 tile using the batch processor and recorded 'Actions'. With transparent `.png` images, this looks great.

The problem is that some of the images have a coloured background. If an image has a coloured background a white border around the image looks quite awful.

[image: This is how the current output looks.]

How do I dynamically resize the non-transparent images of different colours and sizes to 200x200 square `.jpg` images? I can do it manually with the colour-picker but is there another option?

As you can see it is only a problem when images have a coloured background.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the current batch you have, it is difficult to see what you are doing purely by explanation, the code means a lot more to us. If however the `batch` you are referring to is not using actual code and you use the Photoshop like batch editor, then you are on the wrong forum.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to use the batch-file tag and not the batch-processing one?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I included an image. It is not actual code. I use 'Actions' in Photoshop to execute a series of tasks. If you can point me to any solution I would be grateful. (It does not have to be Photoshop)

Comment: Yes, the batch-file tag is what got you the response.

Comment: If I could record the action to use the 'color-picker' tool on 1 pixel in the top left corner that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following script somewhere convenient:

```js
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
myDocument.colorSamplers.removeAll(); 
var myColourSampler = myDocument.colorSamplers.add([1 , 1]); 
app.backgroundColor = myColourSampler.color;
```

- At the start of the action your going to use for your batch process, record the opening of the script (File >> Scripts >> Browse...), then go and get the script.
- It will take the colour of the top left pixel and set it as the background colour, your action should do the rest